# Usage of the LOCAL_QUORUM consistency level in Datastax driver

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-3.0

For some reasons I need to query a particular datacenter within my cassandra cluster. According to [the documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html#dmlConfigConsistency__dml-config-read-consistency), I can use the `LOCAL_QUORUM` consistency level:

> Returns the record after a quorum of replicas in the current
>   datacenter as the coordinator has reported. Avoids latency of
>   inter-datacenter communication.

Do I correctly understand, that in order to specify a particular datacenter for the current query, I have to build a cluster on the given endpoint belonging to this particular DC?

Say, I have two DC's with the following nodes:

```
DC1: 172.0.1.1, 172.0.1.2
DC1: 172.0.2.1, 172.0.2.2
```

So, to work with DC1, I build a cluster as:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("172.0.1.1").build();
Session session = cluster.connect();
Statement statement = session.prepare("select * from ...").bind().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM);
ResultSet resultSet = session.execute(session);
```

Is it a proper way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By itself, `DCAwwareRoundRobinPolicy` will pick the data center that it finds with the "least network distance" algorithm.  To ensure it connects where you want, you should specify the DC as a parameter.

Here is how I tell our dev teams to do it:

```
Builder builder = Cluster.builder()
  .addContactPoints(nodes)
  .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions()
    .setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE))
  .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(
    new DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.Builder()
      .withLocalDc("DC1").build()))
  .withPoolingOptions(options);
```

Note: this may or may not be applicable to your situation, but do I recommend using the `TokenAwarePolicy` with the `DCAwareRoundRobin` nested *inside* it (specifying the local DC).  That way any operation specifying the partition key will automatically route to the correct node, skipping the need for an extra hop required with a coordinator node.

Comment: Wow :) Thanks a lot

Comment: No problem!  Although in my example I did specify a consistency level of `LOCAL_ONE`, so you'll want to adjust that, too.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `Cluster` class [documentation](http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.3/index.html?com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.html):

> A cluster object maintains a permanent connection to one of the
>   cluster nodes which it uses solely to maintain information on the
>   state and current topology of the cluster

Also, because [a default load balancing policy](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.3/manual/load_balancing/) is `DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy` this approach should work fine as expected.